# Using JSONP with the EmberJS router?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jsonp, ember.js

How to use JSONP under a ajax get under emberJS router. Can anyone share a sample code which uses the ajax/getJSON requests to populate the data ?

In the latest application structure http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/ Controller create is managed by the Router initialization. What is the best way to write an AJAX get for controller   keeping the router code similar to what is proposed in the application structure ember guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://trek.github.com/ (Especially the "Loading External Data" part) for an example.
From that it would seem that your AJAX gets should reside in you models not and not directly in your router. But I may be over interpreting things.

Comment: @trek-glowacki notes that this link is no longer valid, because it refers to an out-dated Ember.js router design.  Unfortunately, there is not an updated version relevant to the current Ember.js architecture.